# JSON object string in C#, How to get article URL from the following JSON object in c#

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to use NewsAPI to get relevant articles but the return type is JSON object. I have never worked with JSON objects before and every answer I looked up seems personalized for each specific JSON object which I couldn't really understand how to apply to mine.

The following code in c#...

```
using System.Net;

var url = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?" +
      "country=us&" +
      "apiKey=*mySpecificKey*";

var json = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
```

gives me a JSON object that looks like this...

```
{

"status": "ok",
"totalResults": 38,
-
"articles": [
    -
    {
        -
        "source": {
            "id": "cnn",
            "name": "CNN"
        },
        "author": "Frederik Pleitgen and Mary Ilyushina, CNN",
        "title": "US is out of the picture in Syria-Turkey crisis. Putin now owns this mess - CNN",
        "description": "As US President Donald Trump hailed the agreement his administration negotiated with the Turks for northern Syria as \"a great day for civilization,\" the Turks quickly dumped cold water over the White House's euphoria, refusing to even call the deal a ceasefir…",
        "url": "https://www.cnn.com/2019/10/20/middleeast/putin-now-owns-this-mess-intl/index.html",
        "urlToImage": "https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/190827100831-russia-turkey-aviation-politics-diplomacy-super-tease.jpg",
        "publishedAt": "2019-10-20T05:16:00Z",
        "content": "Moscow (CNN)As US President Donald Trump hailed the agreement his administration negotiated with the Turks for northern Syria as \"a great day for civilization,\" the Turks quickly dumped cold water over the White House's euphoria, refusing to even call the dea… [+6294 chars]"
    },
    -
    {
        -
        "source": {
            "id": null,
            "name": "Bbc.com"

    ... and so on.
```

And I need to access the url of each article. As an extremely novice user of JSON object, how would I go about getting just the URL from each article? Please explain as thoroughly as possible. 
Thank you ahead of time for any help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use well known lib Newtonsoft.Json for this . Here i create the overall model of your JSON result via 3 classes. Main class is Result.json,
which contains articles and sources. And what you have to do after requesting and getting your json, you have to deserialize it. And through LINQ i get all urls.

Take a look  this code. I have already tested, it works.

```
    public class Source
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public class Article
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "author")]
    public string Author { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "urlToImage")]
    public string UtlToImage { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "publishedAt")]
    public string PublishedAt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "content")]
    public string Content { get;set; }
}

public class  ResultJson
{

    public List<Source> Sources { get; set; }

    public List<Article> Articles { get; set; }
}

public class Programm 
{
        var json = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);

        var articles = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultJson>(json).Articles.ToList();

        List<string> allUrls = new List<string>();

        allUrls = articles.Select(u => u.Url).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much man!! Each URL is stored separately in allUrls right? The only reason I'm asking is when I try to change a label I have so it stores each url on a new line using a for loop (label.Text += allUrls.ElementAt(i) + "\n") it's coming out as one big paragraph instead. It's no biggie in my case cause I just needed the urls but I just thought I'd ask. Thanks again man.

Comment: Yes each url stored separatly in allUrls List. And you can loop through that list ang get each of them.